# Java files are not getting compiled

Tags: java, ant

When the source files are part of a package and the directory structure of the source tree is not following the package hierarchy, `javac` `ant` task is unable to compile the java classes. However I see that on different machines, the same

> build.xml

file runs fine.

For example if I have a java file with the package as `com.abc.myapp.server.base` and if my source file is placed under `C:\mySource\base` folder, `javac` is unable to compile this class.
However if I move my `.java` source file under `C:\mySource\com\abc\myapp\server\base` folder, everything goes fine.

I am using **ANT 1.8.0** version and **JDK 1.7.0_17** version on **Windows 7**.

Please advise

Comment: You must follow the hierarchy if your source file is in a certain package.

Comment: post the build.xml, so we can have more details and help you...

Comment: This one is for you, please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not setting up your directory structure to match the packages of your java source files.  The source for the class "org.example.abc.HelloWorld" should live in a directory like /src/org/example/abc.

Typically, you'd want your build.xml to be at the top-level of whatever project you're trying to build, and then the javac task inside it can reference the source directory where your package structure starts.

Something like this:

```
<project name="example" default="compile">
    <target name="compile" description="compiles">
        <mkdir dir="build"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

This is obviously very over simplified, but should help get you started.

If you're still having trouble, post your build.xml and some description of your project's layout so we can help.